# How do you calculate Resolve Points when Multi-classing?

Tags: multi-classing, starfinder

How do you calculate Resolve Points when Multi-classing?

The standard is half PC's level (minimum 1) + Class Key Ability mod (EX: Operator's Dex mod).

Our GM had us make level 5 PCs and I chose to multi-class to Operator 3 and Technomancer 2. How do I calculate his Resolve Points? Is it half level (minimum 1) + Class Key ability per Specific class,

> EX  Lv 5 Operator 3 (Dex 16/+3), Technomancer 2 (Int 18)
>
> Lv 3 Operator = 1/2 Lv + 3 = 4
>
> Lv 2 Technomancer = 1/2 Lv + 4= 5
>
> PC Lv 5 = 9 Resolve

or total level using the first class a primary?

> EX  Lv 5 Operator 3 (Dex 16/+3), Technomancer 2 (Int 18)
>
> Lv5 = 1/2 Lv + Dex mod +3 = 5 Resolve points

Comment: I can see why you asked - the section on Resolve Points alone isn't very helpful, and "multiclassing" is in neither the glossary nor the index. C'mon, Paizo, get it together. :P

Answer (score 14):

## Use your full character level and better key ability score.

Calculate separately, or together? From SCR p. 22 (emphasis added):

> You have a number of Resolve points equal to half your **character** level (rounded down, but minimum 1) + the modifier of your key ability score...

OK, but what do I use for key ability score? From p. 27:

> It's important to keep track of which effects and prerequisites rely on a character level versus class level... A multiclassed character can have more than one key ability score... For any key ability score calculation not tied to class, such as determining your maximum Resolve Points, **use whichever key ability score has the highest value** (and therefore the highest modifier).

So it's actually neither of your suggestions - you use the total character level/2 (2), plus your *best* key ability score (Int +4), for a total of **6** Resolve Points. This makes sense, as an Operator 4 with Dex 16, Int 16 (5 RP) who multiclassed to Op 4/Technomancer 1 would otherwise have 9 RP - a substantial and uncalled-for bonus over the schlub who went to Op 5 and remained at RP 5.

Comment: Aside: I used "SCR" as an abbreviation because "Starfinder Core Rulebook" is what it says on the front page, but I don't know if that's the convention that will take hold. Looks like we'll have to wait for starfindersrd.com to go live on 8/31 and have a peek at their "Abbreviations" section.